# How to return Future<List<Object>> from List<DocuementReference>>?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a method to convert a List to Future<List>.
This is the method I created.

```
    static Future<List<Product?>> fromProductRefList(
      List<DocumentReference> ref) async {
      List<Product> shopProductList = [];
      ref.forEach((productRef) async {
        final productDoc = productRef.get();
        final product = await Product.fromDocument(await productDoc);
        shopProductList.add(product!);
    });

      print('shopProductList: $shopProductList');
      return shopProductList;
  }
```

and called it in cubit,

```
  void mapProductToState() async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: MyProductStatus.loadding));
    final shop = _shopBloc.state.shop;
    List<Product?> productList = [];

    if (shop.shopProductRef.isNotEmpty) {
      final productList = Product.fromProductRefList(shop.shopProductRef);
    }

    emit(state.copyWith(
      shop: shop,
      productList: productList,
      status: MyProductStatus.loaded,
    ));
  }
```

VScode shows no error but when I run the code, fromProductRefList return empty list. Seems like fromProductRefList did not wait for the Document actually get() from the database and just return.

When I add a second delay in fromProductRefList before returning the shopProductList, everything works as expected.

I have read another question on stackoverflow suggest using asyncMap() but I am not sure how to apply it in my case.

Edit:
When I add a delay, the method return without any issue. If not, it will return a empty list

```
static Future<List<Product?>> fromProductRefList(
      List<DocumentReference> ref) async {
    List<Product> shopProductList = [];
    ref.forEach((productRef) async {
      final productDoc = productRef.get();
      final product = await Product.fromDocument(await productDoc);
      shopProductList.add(product!);
    });

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    print('shopProductList: $shopProductList');
    return shopProductList;
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `await` keyword, to actually wait for the call. It only compiles, because you also declare a **new** variable of name `productList`, shadowing the already existing one.

So this line:

```
final productList = Product.fromProductRefList(shop.shopProductRef);
```

should read:

```
productList = await Product.fromProductRefList(shop.shopProductRef);
```

In addition, this does not do what you think it does:

```
ref.forEach((productRef) async {
```

It does *not* wait for each call. Please use a normal `for` flow control structure and `await` the async call, not the `forEach` method. The `forEach` method will no wait for the Futures returned from the methods.

Comment: Hi @nvoigt, thanks for the answer. I did the change you mentioned but the issue still exist.

Comment: Are you sure that a cubit is teh rigth choice? It looks fairly complicated, it should be a full blown BLoC. The fact that your async method returns a void instead of a future makes me think you are missing more in parts you haven't posted yet.

Comment: I have edited my question to included a temporary solution to make my method work. I think the method didn't wait for the forEach function to finish

Comment: Thanks nvoigt! It work flawlessly even tho I find it really weird as I thought forEach should behave similar with regular for.

Comment: Well, the `forEach` method does exactly what a normal `for` does, it executes your method once per item. It does not wait for the Future returned. If you want that, you have to program it.